# failed to load resource in vue js and Laravel project

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

working with Vue js and Laravel project. using ivuew js library also. how ever when upload a picture here there should be `trash` icon in the middle of image.

```
<div class="demo-upload-list-cover">
        <Icon type="ios-trash-outline" @click="deleteImage"></Icon> // trash icon here
</div>
```

but after upload image to the system not visible trash icon and console generate following error messages

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
HKGrotesk-Bold.woff2:1  
      

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
HKGrotesk-Regular.woff2:1


Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
HKGrotesk-Medium.woff:1
       

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
HKGrotesk-Bold.woff:1

       
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
HKGrotesk-Regular.woff:1
       

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)


DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for http://localhost:8000/js/iview.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE


DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for http://localhost:8000/css/bootstrap.min.css.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
```

how to fix it?

Comment: Can you format the error codeblock?

Comment: yes I did it please see it

Comment: I meant to put all the separate items in a big code block with triple backticks: ```. The way you have done for the first piece of code.

Comment: plese see it again I mean I did it